# minimize the number of unique lengths(numbers) in a vector with bounds

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, dynamic-programming

Following problem: I have a vector of n different lenghts. I want to minimize the number of different/unique lenghts in that vector. To do so, I can change those numbers - I know the upper and lower bound of each length even. A specific restriction for my particular problem is that the lengths can only be increased and not decreased. I want to do change the lengths in a way so that the overall change is minimal.

So for examaple I have the numbers 1.5, 2.0 and 3.0. Bounds for each x are [x, x+1.1] (can only be increased). So n=3 and let's say I want to know if I can reduce that to 2 unique numbers and if so - how would be the optimal way. For this example, two possible results would be

2.0, 2.0, 3.0 or

1.5, 3.0, 3.0

Both would reduce the number of different lengths to 2, but the second would be better since I would only need to add 0.5 versus 1.0 in the second example.

Is that a known problem? Any pointers? Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask - wasn't sure where to start.

Comment: * lengths ${}{}$

Comment: I guess dynamic programming may be helpful for your problem.

Comment: You've said that you want "the overall change [to be] minimal" and that you "want to minimize the number of different/unique lengths."  It may not be possible to minimize both simultaneously so you need to be more specific about what it is that you really want to minimize.

Comment: The primary goal is to redude the number of different lengths. The secondary to do that with as little size increase as possible.

Comment: Reduce to what? To $n-1$? Or to some fixed $k<n$?

Comment: I can see how to minimize the number of different lengths if there are no other restrictions on the length, but I'm not sure how to solve the full version of your problem (or if it's hard or not).

Answer (score 0):

You could formulate this as a Linear Program (LP).  Let $\mathbf x$ be your vector of original numbers, and $\mathbf u$ be the vector of corresponding upper bounds.  Let $\mathbf y$ be the amount by which you increase each number.  Then, we can write the following optimization problem.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
p = &\min_{\mathbf y} &&\sum_{i<j}|(x_i+y_i) -(x_j+y_j)| +\alpha\sum_i y_i \\
&\ \ \text{s.t.} && \mathbf x+\mathbf y\leq \mathbf u, \\
&&& \mathbf y \geq \mathbf 0.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

The first part of the objective function measures the difference between each pair of adjusted numbers.  The second part penalizes the overall change, so long as $\alpha > 0$.

This can be recast as an LP by introducing an auxiliary variable $z_{ij}$ for each absolute value:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
p = &\min_{\mathbf y, \mathbf z} &&\sum_{i<j}z_{ij}+\alpha\sum_i y_i \\
&\ \ \text{s.t.} && \mathbf x+\mathbf y\leq \mathbf u, \\
&&& \mathbf y \geq \mathbf 0, \\
&&& z_{ij} \geq (x_i+y_i) -(x_j+y_j), \\
&&& z_{ij} \geq -\left ( (x_i+y_i) -(x_j+y_j)\right ), \ \ \ \forall i < j.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Comment: I think the OP wants an exact solution.

Comment: Well, as the Rolling Stones once so wisely observed, you can't always get what you want. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oqMl5CRoFdk#t=03m07s

Comment: True.  But in that case, there is probably a proof that this is NP-hard.